# Asymptotic expansion function and its inverse

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

Let $f$ be an analytic function asymptotic to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z^n}$ for $z\to\infty$ with $a_0=0$ and $a_1\neq0$. Let $g$ be the inverse of $f$, meaning $g\circ f=id$. Let $g$ be asymptotic to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{w^n}$ for $z\to\infty$.

*Question: Is the compositional inverse of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z^n}$ equal to the asymptotic expansion of $g(w)?$*

In other words: is taking the asymptotic expansion and compositional inverse compatible?

I am wondering this, since I have proved certain properties for the asymptotic expansion of a function, and want to see if I could use it on the inverse of a function, without knowing the actual functional inverse but only the inverse of the asymptotic power series.

Comment: what do you mean by $f$ asymptotic to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z^n}$? Is that the Laurent series of $f$ at infinity?

Comment: I mean $f(z)\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z^n}$ for $z\to\infty$ as described in the  [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) @Conrad

Comment: Have a look at section 8.4 on page 21 of F. W. J. Olver's book *Asymptotics and Special Functions*. See also section 2 in the paper https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=150751